# ¿TableView en JavaFX no se completa con los datos?

Tags: java, javafx, tablas, scenebuilder

estoy haciendo una aplicación la cual tiene como objetivo extraer datos de inputs e insertarlos en una TableView en donde los datos pertenecen a la clase "Cheque" como atributos de la misma.
El problema es que no me carga los datos en la tabla, al darle click al botón "Agregar" solo se muestra la tabla vacía sin ningún dato agregado.
Utilice Scene Builder para construir toda la interfaz grafica y en el boton "Agregar" añadi la función "CargarCheque". Para ligar las columnas de la tabla con los atributos del cheque utilice la funcion tabla.setItems(cheques), en donde cheques es un ObservableList, que puede estar pasando?
les adjunto el código:

Código de controller.java

```
package sample;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.*;



public class Controller implements Initializable {



    @FXML
    private TableView<Cheque> tabla;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,String> bancocolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,String> sucursalcolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,Integer> numerochequecolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,String> fechachequecolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,String> titularcolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,String> clientecolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cheque,Float> importecolumn;

    @FXML
    private TextField banco;

    @FXML
    private TextField sucursal;

    @FXML
    private TextField numerocheque;

    @FXML
    private TextField fechache;

    @FXML
    private TextField titular;

    @FXML
    private TextField cliente;

    @FXML
    private TextField importe;




    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


        try {

            bancocolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("banco"));
            numerochequecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("numerocheque"));
            fechachequecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fechacheque"));
            clientecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cliente"));
            sucursalcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sucursal"));
            titularcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("titular"));
            importecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("importe"));


            tabla.setItems(cheques);

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);

        }



    }

    @FXML private final ObservableList<Cheque> cheques = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @FXML public void cargarCheque(ActionEvent event){
        cheques.add(new Cheque(banco.getText(),titular.getText(),cliente.getText(),sucursal.getText(),fechache.getText(),Integer.parseInt(numerocheque.getText()),Float.parseFloat(importe.getText())));
        tabla.refresh();

    }

}
```

Código de la clase Cheque

```
package sample;

public class Cheque {
   String banco,titular,cliente,sucursal,fechacheque;
   Integer numerocheque;
   Float importe;


    public Cheque(String banco,String titular,String cliente,String sucursal,String fechacheque,Integer numerocheque,Float importe){
        this.banco = banco;
        this.sucursal = sucursal;
        this.numerocheque = numerocheque;
        this.fechacheque = fechacheque;
        this.titular = titular;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.importe = importe;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner el tabla.setItems(cheques); en el método cargarCheque, algo así:

```
@FXML public void cargarCheque(ActionEvent event){
    cheques.add(new Cheque(banco.getText(),titular.getText(),cliente.getText(),sucursal.getText(),fechache.getText(),Integer.parseInt(numerocheque.getText()),Float.parseFloat(importe.getText())));
    tabla.setItems(cheques);
}
```

Comment: No anduvo, estoy sospechando que el initializer no este corriendo o algo asi...